# MySQL : Is there a way to reserve x connections for a given user?

Tags: mysql, configuration, database-connection

Given a server with 3 databases (A, B and C) and 3 users (userA, userB, and userC).

One databases **must** always be reachable (db "A"), the two others are less important.

For a MaxConnections of 200, can I tell Mysql to reserve 50 connections for my DB "A" or my User "userA" ?

Or should I have to limit the two other users to 75 connections ?

Comment: maybe something like this? grant usage on *.* to user1234@'%' with max_user_connections 10;

Comment: In fact, I want user A to have a **minimum** of 50 connections available ...

Comment: well, with grant, you have these options http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html. Other than that, I think you'll need some balancer in front of these dbs

Comment: specially if the idea is to have 50 conns available across the servers (like 10+10+30), there's no way for one server to know each other settings I guess

Comment: There is no remote connections. So you tell me I just can limit other users (accounts) ?

Comment: sorry? I don't understand

Comment: You can set max_user_connections 75 to userB and userC, so 50 connections will be always available for userA

Comment: Leo, my enlgish may be bad, sorry !

Comment: OK akuzminsky, it seems to be the only way to achieve my goal. 
Thanks to you both !

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for a minimum connection resource setting. You may have multiple users and have a resource limitation on one of them.

This example allows 200 connection and at least 50 of them for dbA at all times:

```
CREATE USER 'userA'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
    WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 200;
CREATE USER 'userB'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
    WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 75;
CREATE USER 'userC'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
    WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 75;
```

Then use `userA` for connecting to dbA and `userB` and `userC` for connecting to the other two databases.

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/user-resources.html) has a couple additional options you may set per user:

```
MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20
MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10
MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 5
```

Credit to Leo and akuzminsky for the suggestion, in comments, to use the resource_option.